# What is the default value of the respawn attribute on the roslaunch node tag?

Tags: roslaunch, xml, newtags, respawn, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the default value of the respawn attribute on the node tag? Currently the documentation says it's optional, but it does not say what the default value is.

Documentation of the node tag is here.
http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216723/what-is-the-default-value-of-the-respawn-attribute-on-the-roslaunch-node-tag?/) by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3061 on 2015-08-28

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it is not specified, the `respawn` parameter defaults to false.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3